# Application icon in Genymotion

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, eclipse-adt, genymotion

Hiii, I'm develop two class for two xml layout
But when it run, application icon in my genymotion appear double..

Each one icon contain one class from application that i make

**This is my manifest :**

```
....

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="4452000"/>
        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="myapikey"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity2"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>           
    </activity>

....
```

How do I make the application icons into one icon ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove the `<intent-filter>` from the activity you do not want to appear